# How do I utter a message immediately before custom action?

Tags: rasa-nlu

I'm trying to notify a user that a custom action is about to take place. I thought making a story where a simple utterance followed by that action would be enough.

```
## Story changeModel
   * changeModel
     - utter_model_changing
     - changeModel
```

I want the previous bot to say goodbye, a wait, then the next bot to say hello. At the moment though, the wait happens immediately after the user message, then the two bot messages come back concatenated.
E.g.

> "change the model"

long wait

> "
>   Please wait while I get the new bot online.Hey, New Bot here. What can I help you with?"

I've also tried putting multiple dispatcher.utter_message(msg) statements in my custom action but this has the same result as above.

How can I send a message and have it appear for the user before the long custom action is executed?